# Rebuild ExternalProject if source changes

Tags: cmake

I have an external project:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    lighttpd
    URL "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/lighttpd/lighttpd.tar.gz"
    SOURCE_DIR "${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_PATH}/lighttpd"
)

ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    lighttpd copy2build
    COMMAND cp -a ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_PATH}/lighttpd/bin/. ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}
    COMMAND cp -a ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_PATH}/lighttpd/lib/. ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
    DEPENDEES install
)
```

The problem is that CMake is not rebuilding `lighttpd` if `lighttpd.tar.gz` changes. How can I tell CMake to rebuild this external project if `lighttpd.tar.gz` changes?

Comment: What about using the `BUILD_ALWAYS` parameter (listed under "Build Step Options" in [the `ExternalProject_Add` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add))?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem that I don't think `ExternalProject_Add` solves by it's own.

Note that `ExternalProject_Add_Step` has an option `ALWAYS` that you can set to `1` or `0`. We'll use that in the following workaround/solution.

You can compute the hash of the file using the following:

```
file(<MD5|SHA1|SHA224|SHA256|SHA384|SHA512> filename file_hash)
```

You can then save this `variable` as an internal cache variable

```
set(TAR_BALL_HASH ${file_hash} CACHE INTERNAL "")
```

You can then compare the two variables and if they are the same, set the `ALWAYS` option of your `ExternalProject_Add_Step` to `1`, otherwise, set it to `0`.

Comment: `ExternalProject_Add_Step` also has a `DEPENDS` option, which did allow me to specify the `tar.gz`. However, that just resulted in CMake recopying the old lighttpd into `/build/bin` any time the `tar.gz` changed (not untarring and rebuilding). Is there a way to break out the untar/build steps into `Add_Step`s?

Comment: @RPGillespie Sorry, I am not sure. Would be a good question for the CMake mailing list.